# View is shown in iOS 8 but not in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, view, uiviewcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a scene in `storyboard` that is modally presented. Its view controller is a subclass of `UIViewController` and conforms to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. When I run the app in an `iOS 8` simulator, the view is correctly shown, but in an `iOS 7` simulator I see that `viewWillAppear:` method of the view controller is called, but `viewDidAppear:` it is not. However, `viewDidAppear:` is also called in the `iOS 8` simulator.

I don´t know how to debug this, the app doesn't crash and I see no logs in `Xcode`. What could be happening?

I'm using `Xcode 6.4` and I need this app to run in `iOS 7` and above.

Comment: Post some code here .

Comment: @AshishKakkad I don't know what exactly to post, the segue is 'Modal' type and it's set in storyboard from a button.

Comment: What is your code for viewDidAppear

Comment: @AshishKakkad I'm just calling `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` there...

Comment: @AshishKakkad `viewDidAppear:` is not even reached, but `viewWillAppear:` seems to finish... what could be being called in-between?